# Alguém sabe como faço esse caractere no HTML? ( foto abaixo )

Tags: html5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não achei em lugar nenhum esse caractere... preciso colocar em um site, essa "seta" para baixo, só a seta, pura, pra HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da pra fazer com html5 tambem se preferir.

E só utilizar o css para rotaciona-lo e aumentar/diminuir o tamanho.

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">&#10095;</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode produzir este resultado apenas utilizando CSS rotacionando um elemento e trabalhando com suas bordas. Isso evitaria de você ter que inserir mais uma fonte no seu projeto apenas para utilizar um caractere.

```css
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1E90FF, #4169E1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 3px white solid;
  border-right: 3px white solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Já vi sites que implementam esta seta através da biblioteca de ícones [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Para ser mais específico, trata-se deste ícone: http://fontawesome.io/icon/angle-down/

Comment: Vlw irmão, é esse mesmo! obrigado

Comment: @Clayton se a resposta resolveu  o teu problema podes clicar para marcar como aceite.